# Unity multiple servers for rooms

Tags: unity, multiplayer, unity-networking

I have an FPS game that I'd like to make multiplayer. It would need to support multiple matches at once with about 10 players in each. However I want physics to be server-authoritative so that means running a Unity instance.

How do I have multiple Unity processes running on a server, creating/destroy them as needed, having players connect to the instance they need, and so on? How does this vary between uNet/Sockets/LLAPI/Photon/Bolt/etc?

There just seems to be an atrocious lack of information on Unity networking and when people ask online there's almost never any answer, or it's too vague to be useful.

Comment: I'm not an expert in server setup, but I think you might get answers faster if you narrow the scope of your question a little, to just "How do I have multiple Unity processes running on a server, creating/destroy them as needed?" You can save the follow-on questions of how to have "players connect to the instance they need, and so on? How does this vary between uNet/Sockets/LLAPI/Photon/Bolt/etc?" for a separate post. If someone needs to answer *all* of those questions at once, it will often take more time before you get a complete, high-quality answer.

Comment: Are you asking about threading?  Because that alone is a big serious question.  Seems like overkill though, to have threads per game if each game is only going to have about ten players.  How many games do you want per server?  This is going to be a dedicated server?  I think for this to be answered, like @DMGregory said, you're going to have to refine it and add requirements.  Like how many games per server?